# Prove that in $R$ differentiable functions whose derivative is constant $\frac{df}{dx}=k$ are only $f(x)$ = $kx+b$ linear functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Prove that in $R$ differentiable functions whose derivative is constant $\frac{df}{dx}=k$ are only $f(x)$ = $kx+b$ linear functions.

I am thinking that is we can approximate functions with Taylor polynomial than we can say that there are only linear functions whose derivative is constant but I am not sure and maybe without Taylor series we can solve?

Comment: How about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: We didn't yet discuss integrals.

Comment: The [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) tells you that there is $z\in(0,x)$ such that $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(z)=k$. Therefore $f(x)=kx+f(0)$.

Comment: Thanks very much I didn't thought about that!.

Comment: Whenever you need to get information about a function, when having global information about its derivative, the mean value theorem is likely to help you.